# Combining test class and configuration class in one single class?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-test

I have tried to use the same class both for tests definition and for spring context configuration.

Below is code for class `CombineTestAndConfigTry` which serves both as test definition and context definition for itself.

`bean1` is just stub bean. `bean2` should contain the name of the class and `bean3` should contain a reference to a class.

It is evident, that Spring is wrapping test class instance into different class, so tests are failed.

Simultaneously, it appeared, that some information can be passed from test class to spring context.

The question is: how normal is such usage and which problems can I meet if utilize it?

Also it is interesting (and how to know), how many times `@Autowired` is executed? Two times because of both roles? Or one time because Spring sees the situation?

```
@Configuration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CombineTestAndConfigTry.class)
public class CombineTestAndConfigTry {


   public static class MyBean1 {
      {
         System.out.println("MyBean1 constructor");
      }
   }

   public static class MyBean2 {

      private String configName;

      {
         System.out.println("MyBean2 constructor");
      }

      public String getConfigName() {
         return configName;
      }

      public void setConfigName(String configName) {
         this.configName = configName;
         System.out.println("MyBean2#configName set");
      }
   }

   public static class MyBean3 {

      private CombineTestAndConfigTry testInstance;

      {
         System.out.println("MyBean3 constructor");
      }

      public CombineTestAndConfigTry getTestInstance() {
         return testInstance;
      }

      public void setTestInstance(CombineTestAndConfigTry testInstance) {
         this.testInstance = testInstance;
         System.out.println("MyBean3#testInstance set");
      }
   }

   public String getConfigName() {
      return getClass().getSimpleName();
   }

   @Bean
   public MyBean1 myBean1() {
      return new MyBean1();
   }

   @Bean
   public MyBean2 myBean2() {
      MyBean2 ans = new MyBean2();
      ans.setConfigName( getConfigName() );
      return ans;
   }

   @Bean
   public MyBean3 myBean3() {
      MyBean3 ans = new MyBean3();
      ans.setTestInstance(this);
      return ans;
   }

   @Autowired
   public MyBean1 myBean1;

   @Autowired
   public MyBean2 myBean2;

   @Autowired
   public MyBean3 myBean3;

   @Test
   public void testGetConfigName() {
      assertEquals( getConfigName(), myBean2.getConfigName() );
   }

   @Test
   public void testGetTestInstance() {
      assertSame(this, myBean3.getTestInstance());
   }

}
```

Comment: Don't do this, configuration and tests are different things and you will only confuse the framework let alone other developers. You will now end up with 2 instances one for the configuration and one for the test...

Answer (score 1):

My answer to your question is: don't do it (this way).

One of the most important rules of "clean coding" (see the book by Robert Martin) is the SRP - single responsibility principle. Any class (and any method within) is there to do one thing; and one thing only. Meaning: "need of change" should always be coming from one "source"; and not several.

Long story short: what you are asking for is considered (very) bad practice.

If you are doing it in order to avoid another principle DRY (dont-repeat-yourself) ... then think about ways to change your design.

Comment: I am seeking. Don't see any other way yet. Anyway those "principles" shouldn't regarded as axioms.

Comment: Sure. But for me they are very close to axioms. When you don't follow them, you most likely end up with code that is harder to read and maintain. And those two properties are two most important ones that source code has; in my eyes. But no need to get into opinion-based discussions here. As with everything, the developer has to do the balancing between what rules ask for, and what makes the most sense for a specific situation.